# Segmentation fault (core dumped) error when installing pachages with pip3 on virtualenv

Tags: python3, virtualenv

I am working with Ubuntu 21.10 and I just installed python3.6 using this tutorial:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70395169/how-to-install-python-3-6-on-ubuntu-21-10
After that I created a virtual environment using:

```
virtualenv -p python3.6 folder/
```

Now when I try to install packages using:

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

.. I am getting the following error

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

How Can I fix this?

Comment: "Segmentation fault" is Unix-speak for "illegal memory access", it may mean you're missing a shared library. Try `ldd $(type -p pip3)`.

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: 3.6 is older than the version which would have come with ubuntu 21.10. python 3.9. what does `python3 --version` say?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue with pyenv and solved it thanks to this [Workaround2](https://bugs.python.org/issue45700) with rebuilding python 3.6.15 :

```
CFLAGS=-O2 pyenv install 3.6.15
```